# How to link to a different controller in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am learning Ruby on Rails and I have a dumb question about the `link_to` function.

I set up a controller called "home" and I've created "index" as an action .

I've set up devise.  However, when I browse to some links like `sign_in`, `sign_up`, etc. I get this error:

```
Routing Error
No route matches {:controller=>"devise/home"}
```

I've narrowed it down to:

```
<%= link_to "Home", { :controller => "home", :action => "index" }, :class => "navlink" %>
```

This works for my actions for home but not for my devise actions.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Devise creates a set of helper functions for you that generate the correct paths. Run `rake routes` from the command line to see them. You'll get output similar to the following (assuming your Devise model is called `User`).

```
              new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                      {:controller=>"devise/sessions", :action=>"new"}
                  user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                      {:controller=>"devise/sessions", :action=>"create"}
          destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)                     {:controller=>"devise/sessions", :action=>"destroy"}
                 user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                     {:controller=>"devise/passwords", :action=>"create"}
             new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                 {:controller=>"devise/passwords", :action=>"new"}
            edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                {:controller=>"devise/passwords", :action=>"edit"}
                 user_password PUT    /users/password(.:format)                     {:controller=>"devise/passwords", :action=>"update"}
             user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                              {:controller=>"devise/registrations", :action=>"create"}
         new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                      {:controller=>"devise/registrations", :action=>"new"}
        edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                         {:controller=>"devise/registrations", :action=>"edit"}
             user_registration PUT    /users(.:format)                              {:controller=>"devise/registrations", :action=>"update"}
             user_registration DELETE /users(.:format)                              {:controller=>"devise/registrations", :action=>"destroy"}
```

Appending `_path` to the first part of each line gives you the name of the helper function you need to call.

For example, the following would give you a link to the login page:

```
<%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %>
```

Remember if the request is a `DELETE` rather than a `GET` (such as the logout link) you'll need to specify this as part of the call to `link_to`.

```
<%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like I needed to change my call in my template to: <%= link_to "Home", home_index_path, :class => "navlink" %>

Comment: Well, in actual fact `index` actions often don't include the word `index` in the helper function name (in the same way that you don't have to type `index.html` when you visit a website). So it's probably just `home_path`. Best way to find out is to just run `rake routes`!